# Azure Cosmos DB Trigger not working after upgrading to 3.6

Tags: c#, .net, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

we had an existing Cosmos DB on version 3.3, which is now upgraded to 3.6 after which Cosmos DB Triggered functions are unable to start with error saying

Exception type  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException
Exception message   Error indexing method 'GetSomeData' <---
 Cannot create Collection Information for collectionName in database %MongoDbMetadata% with lease leaslineName in database %MongoDbMetadata% : 
 Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0. <--- Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the endpoint for your Cosmos account is different for MongoDB 3.6 versus 3.2. Try using this URI for your Cosmos account in your Azure Function.

[account-name].mongo.cosmos.azure.com

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have specified the correct connection string and still seems to be an issue